# How to add user input value in R

Tags: natty

I am trying to add user input value, both input values given as 5 or it can be anything

```
x <- as.numeric(readline("add value of 5:"));
x1 <- as.numeric(readline("add value of 5:"))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The code works just fine.

Comment: what ever the number has been given by user like x is 5 and x1 is 8, now I want to add these two numbers like y = x+x1, @jsb

Comment: Still waiting for the answer, can any one help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

Well, you answered your own question: `y = x + x1` or `y <- x + x1`.

Comment: I don't want to add with vector function, I have given those two numbers into readline now I want to add these two readline numbers @jsb

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. Could you elaborate what you mean by "add"?